# How to control output key length when using PBKDF2 in openSSL CLI

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

When I use PBKDF2 using openSSL CLI I have something like this:

```
$ echo -n "password" | openssl enc -aes-256-ecb -pbkdf2 -pass stdin -nosalt -iter 2048 -md sha512 -P
key=5ECF922C6FCB8C16494ADDA2E6A8AA7536A35A129E2FE324A37E307763175AF4
```

meaning 32-byte output key.
Is there a way to obtain, let's say, 64-byte output using openSSL CLI?